# How to add Country module as Taxonomy

Tags: 7, entities

is there any way to add [Country Module](http://drupal.org/project/countries) in a taxonomy field.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  The Country Module is much more than just a list of countries.

Comment: ya i know that but is there any way to add that country list for a taxonomy field?

Comment: Do you need to keep it in sync with that module, or is this a one time dump of data into a Taxonomy Field?